# Alamofire 2.0 with xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire, xcode8

I just upgraded to xcode 8. Can Alamofire version 2.0 run with xcode 8? I have tried setting "Use Legacy  Swift Language Version" to Yes but failed to build. I have to use this version because it's a dependency for some other pod (https://github.com/Lotame/LotameDMP-IOS).

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Alamofire is 4.x, it supports Swift 3, I believe Alamofire 3.x supports Swift 2.3, which would work on Xcode 8.

I don't believe you'll be able to use Alamofire 2, though, it's too old by now.

I would suggest you either contact the developer of that library, or fork it and update it to Alamofire 3 or 4 yourself.